What are the the things which husband should provide his wife?
I know that husband has to provide food, clothing, accomodation and basic medical or other expenses of house.
But is he obliged to say provide a car, internet, accessory items, etc?
To sum up, I want to know what has to be provided and to what extent(numbers)?

Here are some essential things a husband should provide to his wife:

Love and affection: Unconditional love, care, and emotional support.

Respect: Treat her with dignity, honor, and respect her opinions and feelings.

Trust: Build and maintain trust, be loyal, and honest.

Communication: Open, honest, and regular communication.

Financial support: Contribute to the household income and manage finances together.

Emotional support: Be a supportive partner, listen, and encourage her.

Intimacy and physical connection: Nurture a healthy and fulfilling intimate relationship.

Personal space and independence: Respect her individuality and personal interests.

Help with household chores: Share responsibilities and work together as a team.

Support her goals and aspirations: Encourage and help her achieve her dreams.

Protection and safety: Ensure her physical and emotional well-being.

Quality time: Spend quality time together, engage in shared activities, and create memories.

Forgiveness and understanding: Practice empathy, forgiveness, and understanding.

Personal growth: Support each other's personal growth and development.

Gratitude and appreciation: Express gratitude and appreciation for each other.


Remember, every relationship is unique, and what works for one couple may not work for another. Communication and mutual understanding are key to a happy and healthy marriage.

Thanks but I wanted to know only about financial part, I found another question that answers it. But thanks for taking time
